# Azure AD: How to redirect user to a specific page

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I have a app hosted in Azure. Currently when a user is authenticated in Azure AD but does not have access to the application, a generic message appears suggesting the user should request access from an administrator.

Now how would I redirect the user to a specific URL when they get this page from Azure AD  ? I see no way to configure this in Azure.

**EDIT**

A little more technical details :

My App is hosted in a serverless Azure App Service. It is an Angular application using msal.js to authenticate.
The App is manually configured in Azure AD using Application Registration tab.

Comment: The error can occur with multiple reasons it needs to  handle redirection based on the return error code with you are application

Comment: no, this is not related to my application. In Azure AD, if a user is not assigned to an application, she gets a special page in Azure that prompts her for requesting access from Administrator. Instead, I would like to redirect o a specific URL (where I have a custom page). Again this is not handled by my app but by Azure AD.

Comment: Hi @sam, In the azure ad we can get the error codes but we can not handle  error such as 401 as app registration is more of authentication not for error handling.since you do not want to handle by you are app ,as a workaround you handle it by IIS (or any other server you are using). If you want to handle it by IIS server please refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/httpredirect/)

Comment: sorry, the 401 was misleading. I don't even know if it's a 401 and i edited my question. The user sees a page that is part of the Azure Oauth flow and it just says the application the user tries to access is not assigned to her principalname. I'm not sure how else to explain, I hope someone with azure ad experience will understand as this is something quite standard.

Comment: You can set its redirect url in the portal, go to AAD>App registrations>your app>Authentication>Redirect URIs.

Comment: The way I understand it, is that this field is for redirecting to the application homepage upon successful login. Again, I want to redirect to a specific page when authentication is successful BUT user does not have access to the application.

Comment: @Sam a little more detail would be helpful: what is your tech stack? what MSAL library are you using? Are you hosting your app on Azure App Services? Are you manually configuring your app for Azure AD or the App Services do that?

Comment: @derisen,  I have edited my question with some extra details. Thank you.

Comment: If you want to handle the redirect to the error page based on the particular error code you need to handle it from your code side.